# Setting connection charset in Doctrine DBAL with comparison to PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, doctrine-orm, character-encoding, dbal

Are there any needs for using `set names ourcharset` with DBAL with PHP `>=5.3.2 and <5.3.6`?

Prior to PHP 5.3.6, the charset option in PDO connection was [ignored](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47802).
If we were running an older version of PHP, we had to use `set names ourcharset`.

Actual Doctrine DBAL 2.5.1 [require](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/v2.5.1/composer.json#L15) PHP `>=5.3.2`.
I can't find what Doctrine team is advising if someone have PHP <5.3.6 version.

DBAL is mostly based on PDO, but it also have some improvements over it, so I was thinking maybe this was improved... but at Doctrine DBAL [documentation page](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/security.html#non-ascii-compatible-charsets-in-mysql) I have found only this:

> Up until PHP 5.3.6 PDO has a security problem when using non ascii
>   compatible charsets. Even if specifying the charset using “SET NAMES”,
>   emulated prepared statements and PDO#quote could not reliably escape
>   values, opening up to potential SQL injections. If you are running PHP
>   5.3.6 you can solve this issue by passing the driver option “charset” to Doctrine PDO MySQL driver. Using SET NAMES does not suffice!

In PDO to this time I have done:

```php
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.$_SESSION['options']['host'].';port='.$_SESSION['options']['port'].';dbname='.$_SESSION['options']['dbname'].';charset='.$_SESSION['options']['charset'];
try {
    $conn = new \PDO($dsn, $_SESSION['options']['user'], $_SESSION['options']['pass']);
    if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.6', '<')) //is this required with DBAL? 
        $conn->exec("set names {$_SESSION['options']['charset']}");
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

With DBAL it's:

```php
<?php
require_once "lib/autoload.php";
$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$params = array(
    'dbname' => $_SESSION['options']['dbname'],
    'user' => $_SESSION['options']['user'],
    'password' => $_SESSION['options']['pass'],
    'host' => $_SESSION['options']['host'],
    'port' => $_SESSION['options']['port'],
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => $_SESSION['options']['charset'],
);
try {
    $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks that DBAL do not improved here anything.
So, if there is possibility that our app will used with PHP between `>=5.3.2 and <5.3.6`, then yes, use additional `SET NAMES`:

```php
<?php
require_once "lib/autoload.php";
$config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$params = array(
    'dbname' => $_SESSION['options']['dbname'],
    'user' => $_SESSION['options']['user'],
    'password' => $_SESSION['options']['pass'],
    'host' => $_SESSION['options']['host'],
    'port' => $_SESSION['options']['port'],
    'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
    'charset' => $_SESSION['options']['charset'],
);
if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.6', '<'))
    $params['driverOptions'] = array(1002=>'SET NAMES '.$_SESSION['options']['charset']); 
                                //"1002" is value of constant MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND
try {
    $conn = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($params, $config);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    trigger_error($e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
?>
```